# SSIS - Simple package completing with blue warning but no error

Tags: ssis

I am looking for some advice as to why my packages are completing but with a blue completion message and not a standard green message?

[image: Blue message]

I have created quite a few packages in the last few weeks and they have all been working ok.  However it seems that whatever I create at the moment is giving me the blue message?  I have created a new solution / project / package in Visual Studio 2017 and created a simple File System Task which performs a simple copy directory command and it still occurs.  The Progress output gives me no clues:

[image: Progress Output]

Is there somewhere I can go to give me a indication of what the issue is?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: I have been getting blue messages since SQL 2012. There's no error/warning. Since its a hyperlink, it is of blue color. Unless you dont have any error in log / progress tab, you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback.  Just seems strange that it can go from being Green to Blue though?  I've also got examples where an extract is not looping through all iterations as expected, most likely due to an ODBC driver issue and again all I get is a blue message and no error.

Comment: The green tick or red cross is the only thing you should worry about :)

Comment: I've never seen this message as green on my screen.  It's always been blue.